# Como criar filtros de pesquisa no Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Preciso criar um sistema de busca que receba dados através de Inputs, select e checkbox.

Minha form para pesquisa:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" action="{!! url('/pesquisar') !!}" method="post" style="margin-left: 25%;margin-bottom: 3%;">

    <div class="form-group">
      {!! csrf_field() !!}
      <input type="text" name="texto" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar" style="width: 600px;">

    </div>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
       <input type="checkbox" id="semimagem" value="semimagem" name="semimagem"> Sem imagem
      </label>
      <select class="form-control" id="status">
        <option value="1">Ativo</option>
        <option value="0">Desabilitado</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Função pesquisa do Controller

```
    public function Pesquisar()
   {
     $texto = Input::get('texto');
     $status = Input::get('status');
     $pesquisa = Produtos::where('erp_status', 'like', '%'.$status.'%')
    ->orWhere('erp_cost','like','%'.$texto.'%')
    ->orWhere('erp_productid','like','%'.$texto.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('descricao', function ($query) use ($texto) {
        $query->where('erp_name', 'like', '%'.$texto.'%');
    })
    ->orderBy('erp_status')
    ->paginate(20);
```

Minhas rotas:

```
Route::get('pesquisar','ProdutosController@pesquisar');
Route::post('pesquisar','ProdutosController@pesquisar');
```

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: O que aconteceu? tem erros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua rota pode ser "any" assim você receberá tanto requisições "get" quanto "post".

```
Route::any('pesquisar','ProdutosController@pesquisar');
```